# Vuejs data not being updated with Vuex current state

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

I have a Laravel application with a Vue.js form wizard with two components. I am carrying data from the first component to the second.

On the first component, the user inputs some values that are then used by a method to set a Vuex state. Then there is a next button that opens the second component where the user inputs are displayed and one of the data inputs is set to the Vuex state from the previous step. Here is the problem: sometimes the data input is not updating with the new state.

First component **:**

```
import { FormMixin } from "../../../../../core/mixins/form/FormMixin";
export default {
  mixins: [FormMixin],
  props: {
    dataCarry: {},
  },
  data() {
    return {
      inputs: {
        amount_local: "",
      }
    };
  },

  methods: {
    goNext() {
      this.preloader = true;
      this.fieldStatus = {};
      this.fieldStatus.isSubmit = true;
      if (this.isValidForm()) {
        this.convert();
        this.$emit("next", true, this.inputs);
        this.preloader = true;
      }
    },
    convert() {
      let payLoad = `${this.$store.state.country.localCurrency}_${this.$store.state.currency.current}`;
      //let payLoad = `USD_MYR`;
      console.log(payLoad);
      this.loading = true;
      axios
        .get(
          `https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=${payLoad}&compact=ultra&apiKey=REDACTED`
        )
        .then((response) => {
          let exchangeRate = JSON.stringify(response).replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, "");

          let conversionAmt = (
            parseFloat(this.inputs.amount_local) * parseFloat(exchangeRate)
          ).toFixed(2);

          this.$store.commit("changeAmountConverted", conversionAmt);

          this.getFees(conversionAmt);

        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.errored = true;
        })
        .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
    },
    getFees(amount) {
      if (this.$store.state.currency.current === "USD") {
        var a = amount;
        var b = (a * 0.0349) + 0.49;
        this.$store.commit("changeFees", Math.round(b * 100) / 100);
      }

      var foo = parseFloat(this.$store.state.userInputs.fees);
      var bar = parseFloat(this.$store.state.userInputs.amount_converted);
      var total = foo + bar;
      this.$store.commit("changeTotal", total);
    },

  },

};
```

Second component **:**

```
import { FormMixin } from "../../../../../core/mixins/form/FormMixin";
export default {
  mixins: [FormMixin],
  props: {
    dataCarry: {},
  },
  data() {
    return {
      preloader: false,
      inputs: {
        fees: this.$store.state.userInputs.fees,
        total: this.$store.state.userInputs.total,
        amount_converted: this.$store.state.userInputs.amount_converted,
        status: "unpaid",
        paypal_id: "0",
      },
    };
  },
```

UPDATE: My Vuex code **:**

```
export default {
  state: {
    amount_converted: "0",
    fees: "0",
    total: "0",
    errors: [],
  },

  getters: {
    getAmountConverted: function (state) {
      return `${state.amount_converted}`;
    },
    getFees: function (state) {
      return `${state.fees}`;
    },
    getTotal: function (state) {
      return `${state.total}`;
    },
  },

  actions: {
    changeAmountConverted({ commit }, payload) {
      commit("changeAmountConverted", payload);
    },
    changeFees({ commit }, payload) {
      commit("changeFees", payload);
    },
    changeTotal({ commit }, payload) {
      commit("changeTotal", payload);
    },
  },

  mutations: {
    changeAmountConverted(state, payload) {
      state.amount_converted = payload;
    },
    changeFees(state, payload) {
      state.fees = payload;
    },
    changeTotal(state, payload) {
      state.total = payload;
    },
  },
};
```

In the second components fees, total, and amount_converted do not get updated if the user goes back and changes the inputs.

I tried using `object.assign(this.$data, this.initialData());` and `window.location.reload()` to clear the data when the back button is clicked with no luck.

Comment: Can you share your state code? Are you using SPA?

Comment: Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70434106/modules-vs-multiple-vuex-store-files/70434581#70434581). I think this way can helps you.

Comment: Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70434106/modules-vs-multiple-vuex-store-files/70434581#70434581). I think this way can help you

Comment: @gguney I have added it

Comment: Firstly, when you call "changeAmountConverted" where is it in your vuex? And you should use getters to get store date.

Comment: Please read: https://v3.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html or v4 if you are using Vue3