# How to access state in the other module's state (vuex)?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have two modules.

module1.js

```
export default {
  state: () => ({
    array: [
      {
        property: value
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

module2.js

```
export default {
  state: () => ({
    array: [
      {
        property: structuredClone(this.$store.state.module1.array[0])
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

I want to access a state from one module in the state in other module. How to do that?

Tried to use context in state (of course didn't work). My code generates an error ($store isn't defined)

Comment: Please check this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70434106/modules-vs-multiple-vuex-store-files/70434581#70434581)

Comment: Consider updating the question with the details, it's unclear why you need that. It's a mistake to access `this` inside an arrow, specifically because an instance doesn't exist inside state factory any way. Move this code to a getter, or use some common function that provides initial state for both modules

Comment: Believe what you are looking for is rootState: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#accessing-global-assets-in-namespaced-modules. This will allow one module to access state (and getters, actions, etc) from other modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that, but you can use a getter because it gives you access to the root state.

```
// module 1
export default {
  state: {
    array: [
      {
        property: value
      }
    ]
  }
}

// module 2
export default {
  getters: {
    myGetter(state, getters, rootState) {
      console.log(rootState.module1.array[0]);
    }
  }
}
```