# Uncaught TypeError: this is undefined vuex login

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuex

```
<script setup>
import { useLayout } from '@/layout/composables/layout';
import { ref, computed ,onMounted} from 'vue';
import AppConfig from '@/layout/AppConfig.vue';
import auth from '@/auth';

const { layoutConfig, contextPath } = useLayout();

const user = ref({});

const checked = ref(false);
const submitted = ref(false);

const logoUrl = computed(() => {
    return `${contextPath}layout/images/${layoutConfig.darkTheme.value ? 'logo-white' : 'logo-dark'}.svg`;
});

const Login = () => {
  submitted.value = true;

  if (user.value.email && user.value.password) {

  this.$store.dispatch("auth/login", user);
  }
};
onMounted(() => {
      auth.authForm('#firebaseui-auth-container')
    });
</script>
```

i am trying to store vuex login but this this.$store.dispatch("auth/login", user); this line i ge t a error (this.$store.dispatch("auth/login", user);).how to solve this problem

Comment: Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70434106/modules-vs-multiple-vuex-store-files/70434581#70434581). I described it completely about that.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking,

```html
<script setup>
/* you are here */
</script>
```

is a shorthand syntax for

```html
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    /* you are here */
  }
})
</script>
```

Inside the `setup()` function there is no `this`.

Ok, so how do I access the store?

```html
<script setup>
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

const store = useStore();
          /*   finds the store of your Vue app
           *     (a.k.a `this.$store` in Options API)
           */

//...

const Login = () => {
  submitted.value = true;
  if (user.value.email && user.value.password) {
    store.dispatch("auth/login", user);
 // 
  }
};
</script>
```